# Set $scope.parameter, ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I got a `main.html` file, inside that I got a `section` that is visible/hidden depending on the state of a `$scope.parameter`. This `main.html` is used in two of my routes, one is the 'main' other is a sub-route. The look like this,

```
.state('medications', {
      url: '/medications',
      templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
      controller: 'mainController',
      resolve: {
      postPromise: ['medicationservice', function(medicationservice) {
           return medicationservice.getAll();
         }]
        }
      })
 .state('medications.add', {
      url: '/add',
      templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
      controller: 'mainController'
 })
```

So what I would like to do in this case is set that `$scope.parameter` to show this `section`. I have seen this examples but I don't get how I set what controller it should use.

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts', {
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
  controller: function($scope){
    $scope.title = 'My Contacts';
  }
})
```

How do I set a parameter with explcitly setting the controller name?

Comment: Have you tried putting the parameter in a service, then referring to that within your Controller (perhaps though another resolve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Make it a `stateParams` (recommended):

```
.state('medications', {
   params: {showSection: false},
   //...

.state('medications.add', {
   params: {showSection: true},
   //...
```

And set your `$scope` variable in `mainController` to that `$stateParam`:

```
$scope.$watch($stateParams.showSection, function(){
   $scope.parameter = $stateParams.showSection;
}, true);
```

**Option 2**:

Watch the `$stateChangeStart` event and change your `$scope` variable according to `toState`:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    $scope.parameter = toState === 'medications' ? false : true;
})
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the `params`, but this solution does not work. It seems as the `showSection` is not triggered with sub state. I can confirm that it actually does set the `showSection` when making it a seperate state.

Comment: @Dejan.S updated my answer, since it's the same controller for both states, i believe a `$watch` should solve the problem and update your variable on state change.

Comment: Is `$watch` related to angularjs or ui-router? Thanks. Do you know how to trigger a function from a state?

Comment: `$watch` is angular, what do you mean by `trigger a function from a state`?

Comment: like if I want to trigger a function inside my controller from the state, just like I assign the parameter I would like to trigger a function.

Comment: If i understand correctly, the source of your problems is that the `controller` is not reloaded on `stateChange` due to the fact that it's the same controller for both states. so the solution would be to trigger the functions / changes you want on `$stateChangeStart` like option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'data' object of $state:

```
 .state('medications.add', {
    url: '/add',
    templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
    controller: 'mainController',
    data: { myParameter: 'true' }
 })
```

Then, in the controller, you can access the data using the $state service. Assign the data to the scope of the controller and you're good to go:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('myController',function($scope,$state){
    $scope.myParameter = $state.data.myParameter;
});
```